# how to get category name from category id?

Tags: joomla, categories

I am new in joomla.In my module i have to give select category option. I tried to get category name from back-end by following code but it doesn't work.Code..

```
$backId=$params->get('mycategory');
$db->setQuery('SELECT cat.title FROM #__categories cat RIGHT JOIN #__content cont ON cat.id = cont.catid WHERE cont.id='.$backId);
$category_title = $db->loadResult();

if ($category_title)
{
    echo $category_title;
}
```

how can i get the category name that i selected.Thanks...

Comment: what is the value of `$backId`?

Comment: $backId is the id of category that i selected from modules back end.

Comment: What version of joomla are you using?

Comment: try to run your query in phpmyadmin to make sure that your query is returning some result.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this may be work..

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$id = jrequest::getint('id');
//match id to cat.id from _categories set to variable $id
$db->setQuery("SELECT cat.title FROM #__categories cat WHERE cat.id='$id'");
$category_title = $db->loadResult();
echo "$id";
echo "$category_title";
```

Comment: it gives me the name of current article category but i need my selected category