# Joomla output category name from category id

Tags: php, joomla

I have the joomla category id stored inside a variable inside a special template overwrite. Now i need to output the category name based on the category id.

```
 echo '<td>' . $catID .'</td>';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get category name from category id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18095899/how-to-get-category-name-from-category-id)

Comment: `$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$db->setQuery("SELECT cat.title FROM #__categories cat WHERE cat.id='$catID'");
$category_title = $db->loadResult();
echo "$catID";
echo "$category_title";`